Cucumber feature: How to use Examples mentioned in Scenario for different environment respectively
The aim is to use Examples set for each particular environment, respectively.
Following is my scenario feature: user is blocked after wrong login 1 time on Dev environment (just for testing) and after 3 times on QA
Scenario Outline: Verify if user is blocked after 3 wrong attempts to login
  When he attempts to login <retries> times with incorrect password
  Then Error Popup should not be displayed
  And Error message is displayed: "Your account is blocked"

  @dev
  Examples:
    | retries |
    | 1       |
  @qa
  Examples:
    | retries |
    | 3       |

I execute the test with a specified environment as follow:
gradle clean e2e-test -Denvironment=dev

I see that the test is executed on Dev, but after retries = 1 (which is passed), it repeats again for retries = 3 , and still on Dev
The same goes to if I execute tests on QA, then it starts first with retries = 1, and then continues with retries = 3, which is not what I expected.
I thought it would recognize each example respectively with the given env. But it seems it executes all the examples for one env.
I expect if I say env = dev, then it should execute example retries = 1 and then it stops. The same for QA. How can I achieve this goal?

I was missing another property: Dcucumber.filter.tags, to specify which example I want to use.
gradle clean e2e-test -Denvironment=dev -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@dev"

